# How to avoid 'arrayof...' in controller response when using IQueryable

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata, iqueryable

I have a webapi controller that returns an Items object like:

```
<Items>
   <Item>
    <Color>PINK</Color>
    <CommercialProductBundle>NOTAPPLICABLE</CommercialProductBundle>
    <Descriptions/>
   </Item>
   <Item>
    <Color>Black</Color>
    <CommercialProductBundle>NOTAPPLICABLE</CommercialProductBundle>
    <Descriptions/>
   </Item>
</Items>
```

In order to use ODATA query functionality I changed the return type from

**public Items GetAllItems()**

where Items is  'List' to

**IQueryable GetAllItems()** .

But then my response shows in stead of  :

```
<ArrayOfItem xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Item>
    <Color>PINK</Color>
    <CommercialProductBundle>NOTAPPLICABLE</CommercialProductBundle>
    <Descriptions/>
</Item>
<Item>
   <Color>Black</Color>
   <CommercialProductBundle>NOTAPPLICABLE</CommercialProductBundle>
   <Descriptions/>
</Item>
</ArrayOfItem>
```

Is there a way to get rid of the 'ArrayOf', showing again the initial xml?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you let your controller derive from `ODataController`? Have you installed the ASP.NET Web API OData V1-3 assemblies? Have you modified your WebApiConfig.cs to map the OData route?

As OData queryability depends on its unique routing convention and the Web API configuration, you might want to follow this tutorial to http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v3/creating-an-odata-endpoint and implement accordingly for getting this querability.